# OS grub page not Loading

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

My laptop was working fine, with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04, when suddenly the grub page stopped loading. Whenever I switch on the laptop, I get the company's name (Asus in this case), with the Intel logo on the bottom right, and the screen gets stuck there. I am not able to access the bios setup either. Can you please help me to resolve this?

This happened suddenly and I've been stuck here for a long time and it has not changed since. I keep restarting, using the power button, but no progress so far. I can at least access all the data that is in Ubuntu 12.04. In the worst case scenario, where this cannot be corrected, what are my options?

Comment: If you can't get to the BIOS setup, that the laptop motherboard must be freezing before it gets to the bootloader that would display the Grub menu. Are there any LED blink diagnostic indicators or beeps at this time? Best hope is that some motherboard component is partially connected (memory for example).

Comment: @jdh Thanks for the reply. I hope the hard disk should be retrievable. In such a case, if I try to run this hard disk with some other system, will I be able to retrieve all data from the Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, it seems likely if you can't get to the BIOS, that the HD is not the problem and should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the relief. will get back after checking with that.